# Is this an unbiased estimator for standard deviation of normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, unbiased-estimator

Suppose we have $n$ samples, with mean $\mu$.

Calculate the average absolute distance from $\mu$, i.e.,
$$ 
y = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - \mu| \>.
$$

Then, take as an estimate of the standard deviation
$$ \tilde \sigma = y\frac{1}{1-1/n}\sqrt{\pi/2}$$

Is it unbiased?

Comment: So, presumably $\mu$ is known *a priori*?

Comment: I've made some edits to your post to markup the math. Please check that I have not introduced any errors.

Comment: **Hint**: Can you find the expectation $\mathbb E |X - \mu|$? It *is* a scaled version of $\sigma$. Find the scale factor.

Comment: We calculate u like sample mean.  The formula you have for is correct.

Comment: I think I proved it was unbiased estimator.  E|X-u| = standard deviation * sqrt(2/pi)

Comment: I was wondering though why we don't see this formula that often for estimating standard deviation?

Comment: Good start, stevie. You have the scale factor correct, but not the conclusion regarding the unbiasedness. Your follow-up question is a good one, with a fairly deep answer. You might consider adding it to the question to make it more prominent. :)

Answer (score 8):

The proposed estimator is not unbiased, at least *if* we indeed know the true mean, $\mu$, and if we are dealing with a normal sample as the title says, where the distribution is symmetric and unimodal and the mean equals the median. Informally, knowing the true mean, makes the mean absolute deviation equal in value to the probability limit of the same expression with $\bar X$ instead of $\mu$. We have

$$ y=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - \mu| = \frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_{X_i\geq \mu} (X_i - \mu)+\sum_{X_j< \mu} (\mu - X_j)\right]$$

Denote $m_1$ the count for the first sum, and $m_2$ the count for the second sum (both are random variables). Then, using also [Wald's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation)

$$E(y) = \frac{1}{n}\Big[E(m_1)E(X\mid X\geq \mu) - E(m_1)\mu + E(m_2)\mu - E(m_2)E(X\mid X\leq \mu)\Big]$$

Since we have the true mean, which is equal to the median, we get $E(m_1)=E(m_2) = n/2$, so the two middle terms cancel, while substituitng for the expected values of the counts, taking common factors and simplifying we arrive at

$$E(y) = \frac{1}{2}\Big[E(X\mid X\geq \mu)  - E(X\mid X\leq \mu)\Big]$$

For the [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), these expected values are

$$E(X\mid X\geq \mu) = \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(0)}{1-\Phi(0)} = \mu +\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$$

$$E(X\mid X\leq \mu) = \mu - \sigma \frac{\phi(0)}{\Phi(0)} = \mu -\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$$

So

$$E(y)=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\mu +\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}  - \mu +\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}\Big] = \sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$$

So the correction factor in $\tilde \sigma$ should be $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ only, for it to be unbiased.

I note that since $X_i - \bar X = (1-1/n)X_i - (1/n)\sum_{j\neq i}X_j$ one suspects that we should examine the case where we do not know $\mu$ and we use the sample mean instead, which I may find the time to do later.

Comment: Simulations indicate that the form with the sample mean is biased (as we might expect, since the variation about the sample mean will tend on average to be lower than the variation around the true mean), though of course as n gets large the bias rapidly disappears.